# How to show Orchestrator, IBM MQ, Load balancer in Deployment diagram

Tags: deployment, uml, diagram, mq, amazon-elb

I need to creat Deployment diagram using UML notation. Diagram has to show IBM MQ, Orchestrator,Load balancer and some data base.

Which elements from Deployment diagram I have to use?

Answer (score 1):

These can all be represented using instances of Nodes and instances of Components. You might want to use stereotypes to add specificity if you feel the design context merits it.